# Permanently set Java version to 8 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, version

When I type `javac -version` on the terminal it says 10.0.2. I type `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` and it switches to version 8. However when I close my terminal and reopen it again it goes back to 10.0.2 version. Is there a way I can set the default to version 8? I'm on Mac High Sierra.

Comment: Put it in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Hi can you please expand your answer? Where is the `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file located? And what do I put there? The command `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `vi ~/.bashrc`

And then enter:

```
export JAVA_HOME=path/to/jdk/jdk1.8.0_102/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Hi I've never used vim before so I didn't know how to save after entering the two commands. I opened `.bashrc` file in finder and entered `export JAVA_HOME=path/to/jdk/jdk1.8.0_102/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` and then saved. I go back to terminal and type `javac -version` I still get 10.0.2

Comment: Did you download jdk 8? Also you will need do a ‘source ~/.bashrc’ after entering the path. Then make sure that the path is correct. Also do ‘echo $PATH’ and check if all the paths are correct.

Comment: Yes I downloaded and installed jdk 8. I typed `echo $PATH` and got `path/to/jdk/jdk1.8.0_102//bin:/Users/edward/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin:/Users/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin:/Users/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@global/bin:/Users/edward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/edward/.rvm/bin:/Users/edward/.rvm/bin`

Comment: You have two forward slashes after the jdk directory.

Comment: @avatarhzh BY path/to/jdk I meant the actual path where you have downloaded the jdk 1.8